# Link UIAlertAction to open another ViewController

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, uialertview, uialertcontroller

Basically i have a uialertaction which needs to show another viewcontroller when pressed. At first i did it but now even though i dont get an error code the viewcontroller which supposed to open is nothing but a black page.

```
            if((user) != nil) {

                let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Succesfull", message: "Logged In", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)

                    self.presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)

                        let delay = 2.0 * Double(NSEC_PER_SEC)

                            let time = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, Int64(delay))
                            dispatch_after(time, dispatch_get_main_queue(), {

                            alert.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: { () -> Void in

                                let logInViewController = BoardViewController()

                                    self.presentViewController(logInViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Actually couple days ago i ran accros to a question such as this but i couldn't understand the answer properly. So can anyone explain me why it happens and doesnt' give any error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your AlertController does not have any actions. You just presenting **logInViewController** after 2 seconds AlertController is shown.

Instead of **dispatch_after** , you can add action to AlertController like this;

```
if(user != nil) {
      let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Succesful", message: "Logged In", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)
      let action = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .Cancel, handler: { // Also action dismisses AlertController when pressed.
            action in

              let logInViewController = BoardViewController()
              self.presentViewController(logInViewController, animated: true, completion: nil) // When press "OK" button, present logInViewController

                }
        )
      alert.addAction(callAction)// add action to alert
      self.presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)// show AlertController
}
```

If you get blank page from **BoardViewController** , then you probably have something wrong in BoardViewController class.

Comment: thank you very much for your answer. yeah my code didnt make any sence at all before now i understood. it works fine. i also edited the BoardViewController class like you suggested.